# Can a bookmark have children? "bookmarks.create: Can't find bookmark for id."

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to add a child bookmark to another bookmark. I realise it sounds odd, but there is a use for it. Problem is I'm getting an exception, "bookmarks.create: Can't find bookmark for id."

Is the exception because Chrome doesn't like the fact that I'm adding a child to a bookmark (rather than a folder), or there another cause for this exception?

```
var cmark = new CrexModule.Cmark();
cmark.parentId = pid; // !!! this cause the add to fail with bookmarks.create: Can't find bookmark for id.
cmark.title = cmarkc.note;
cmark.url = "http://foo.bar.com";
chrome.bookmarks.create(cmark, function (c) {console.log("child added "+c)});
```

this code fails with "bookmarks.create: Can't find bookmark for id.".
pid is the id of a bookmark, which I've verified exists.

If I comment out setting the parentId, the bookmark is successfully created in the default folder.

Comment: please paste the code snippet that you tried.

Comment: What does pid has in it when you run this code?

Comment: 1431 which is the id of a valid bookmark

Comment: seems you have to have the id of the folder..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each item in the bookmark tree is either a folder or a bookmark. Bookmarks cannot have children. Folders can have children.

It is likely that the item identified by `pid` is not a folder, but a regular bookmark. You can verify this by checking if the `pid` object has an empty `url` property. Bookmarks have a `url` property, and folders do not.

Comment: Yes the pid is pointing to a bookmark. I'm deliberately trying to add a child bookmark to a parent bookmark. So the answer to my question is 'no'. Oh well, on to plan b :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you look at the browses . on its GUI. there does not exist any such feature that you can create the list of bookmarks when making a bookmark. what you do is , you create a folder and add the bookmarks in it.

If you are trying to preserve history for navigational purposes. use the JavaScript functions. one is

`window.history.back(-1);`

see some other mehthods here:

http://ntt.cc/2008/01/21/5-ways-to-redirect-url-with-javascript.html